# How to serve static files from my CherryPy applications

Tags: python, cherrypy

I have written a simple web app and I got stuck trying to figure out how to server static files. My static files folder is in a different folder `/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/web3/static` Below is my code, how do I add this static files folder configuration to my app.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import my_web.settings

from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
from django.core.management import call_command

import os
import tempfile
import cherrypy.wsgiserver
import django.core.handlers.wsgi


if __name__ == "__main__":

    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "my_web.settings")

    # Since we use a throwaway database, it needs to be initialized
    # every time Django starts.
    if sys.argv[1] in ('runserver', 'shell'):
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as dbFile:
            my_web.settings.DATABASES['default']['NAME'] = dbFile.name
            call_command('syncdb', interactive=False)
            server = cherrypy.wsgiserver.CherryPyWSGIServer(
                ('0.0.0.0', 8080), django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler(),
                server_name='localhost', numthreads = 10
            )
            try:
                server.start()
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                server.stop()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this... and be sure the user running the app has permission to access the static path.

```
cherrypy.config.update({'tools.staticdir.on': True,
                'tools.staticdir.dir': '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/web3/static'
               })
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ah - I had a trailing comma.  I've updated my answer.  You'll also need to import cherrypy.

Answer (score 0):

Sylvain Hellegouarch has posted a Django CherryPy integration recipe that nicely solves the problem of serving static Django content. See https://bitbucket.org/Lawouach/cherrypy-recipes/src/c8290261eefb82cb5694930f7236606082a941ff/frameworks/django_/?at=default

Just drop the three python files (**init**.py, httplogger.py, and djangoplugin.py) into the directory above your app and change the name of the directory holding your settings.py file in **init**.py to match the directory in your own source code tree.

I also removed the two WebSocketPlugin lines from **init**.py since that was not relevant for my django app.

There is some discussion about the recipe on Sylvain's blog at http://www.defuze.org/archives/262-hosting-a-django-application-on-a-cherrypy-server.html

Comment: And how do you use the server? with `python manage.py runserver`?

Comment: @JavierCárdenas, CherryPy is a web server.  It is an alternative to using the Django builtin development server a.k.a runserver.  In the referenced `__init__.py` the server is launched on the last line by a call to `cherrypy.quickstart()`